# Pandas - combine tables from multiple URLs and extract 1 column to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I am new to Python and coding in general. I am trying to:

1. Pull table information from a website by iterating through multiple pages
2. Combine those tables into one data frame
3. Extract 1 column from that data frame and all of its values into a single list

My attempt:  With the code below, I was able to extract the column I need but it is creating 3 separate lists as opposed to just 1 consolidated list, any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

def get_screener(page):
    screen = requests.get(f'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=idx_sp500&ft=4&o=ticker&r={page}', headers=headers).text
    tables = pd.read_html(screen)
    tables = tables[-2]
    tables.columns = tables.iloc[0]
    tables = tables[1:]

    complist = tables['Company'].tolist()
    print(complist)

    return

for x in range(1, 60, 20):
    get_screener(x)
```

Comment: Kindly provide the `headers`

Comment: what is header?

Comment: You can assume headers to be 'Ticker', 'Company', 'Price, 'Volume'